# What causes this "hem of his garment" aurora (or is it fake)?

Tags: astronomy, meteorology

This picture of a "*hem of his garment*" aurora in Finland is going the rounds today. Is it real, and if so what causes it to be white instead of the green shades normally associated with aurora.

[image]

When I attempt to google the phenomenon for more information, all I get is pages on PInterest results - which I regard as solely click-bait of no intellectual value,, and which raises my suspicions on authenticity.

Comment: Without knowing how the picture was taken, it is hard to say whether it is fake or real. Hence, in order to assess its authenticity, the source must be found. From just looking at how the 'garments' overlap, it is possible that this is a long exposure, taken with a certain set of filters to make the usually green aurora appear white. The glow on the lower right could be a town, looks like typical glow from sodium lamps.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/4dyr3k for what is likely an additional photo from the shoot.

Answer (score 2):

This is FAKE. It is someone running around with a light stick in front of a camera using a long exposure.

Comment: That is so disappointing - but somehow not at all surprising. TY.

Answer (score 2):

It is not a natural phenomena, it was actually produced by "long exposure, a powerful electromagnetic field located next to the lamp"  manipulation photography. Darn it! Here is a link to the original photo along with several other interesting photos,  from the Russian photographer credited with this photo. https://www.yaplakal.com/forum2/topic283586.html